# If $f_n\rightarrow0$ and $|f_n|\leq\frac{1}{x\log x}$, prove that $\int_2^\infty f_ndx\rightarrow0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure

> Let $g(x)=\frac{1}{x\log x}$ for $x>1$. For given *measurable subsets*
>   of $[2,\infty]$ and *non-negative* sequence $c_n$, define
>   $f_n(x):=c_n\chi_{A_n}(x)$.
>   *Prove or disprove* that  if $f_n\rightarrow0$ and $|f_n|\leq g(x)$, then $\displaystyle\int_2^\infty f_nd\mu_L\rightarrow0$. Note that $g$ is not
>   integrable.

After so many examples, I **believe** it to be TRUE. After some trying to prove my guess, I reduced the problem to the case when $A_n=[a_n,b_n]$ **and** $\displaystyle\beta:=\sup_n b_n<\infty$.

Now I just need to prove $$c_n\mu(A_n)=c_n(b_n-a_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$

I'm mixed up a little here.

Comment: Hint: The worst case is $f_n=g(a_n)\chi_{[a_n,\infty)}$ with $a_n\to\infty$. What happens then?

Comment: @Did: I guess you mean $[2,a_n]$.

Comment: @Did, in your example, $\{f_n\}$s are not dominated by $g$

Comment: But the hint of Did still holds, @FardadPouran, if the set is changed to $[2,a_n]$.

Comment: Ah Yes, Indeed:
$$c_n\chi_{[a_n,b_n]}(x)\leq g(b_n)\chi_{[2,b_n]}(x)=:h_n(x)$$
 But how can it help when $\beta=\sup_nb_n<\infty$ ? $\int h_n = \frac{b_n-2}{b_n\log b_n}$

Comment: Then $c_n\chi_{A_n} \le 1/(2\ln 2)\chi_{[2,\beta]}$ for all $n.$ So you have a dominating $L^1$ function.

Comment: @JohnMa Indeed, I typed this comment too quickly (and have been offline since then), thanks for the correction. Yes the idea is to look at the case $f_n=g(a_n)\chi_{[2,a_n]}$ carefully.

Comment: @zhw., Thaks; It worked. You would add it as an answer, too.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, this is true.

1. Let $\beta_n=A_n$. Since $c_n\le \frac{1}{\beta_n\log \beta_n}$, it follows that $\int f_n \le 1/\log \beta_n$.
2. Thus, if the integrals $\int f_n$ fail to converge to zero, we can extract a subsequence with bounded $\beta_n$.
3. But as long as $\beta_n$ stays bounded, we have a uniformly bounded family of functions on a set of finite measure, so dominated convergence theorem applies.